# PRISM + Silverlight VB.NET help needed

Tags: vb.net, silverlight-4.0, prism

I have been a VB6 developer for several years, and switched to .NET couple of years ago.
Since then, I switched to WPF, and now, I am attacking Silverlight + PRISM

I would like to know if anyone here has some **good** and **clear** tutorial/instructions on setting up a View-Switching application in VB, please?

I've searched Google for over a week now, and I haven't really found much clear information, so all my attempts and efforts are going to waste right now.

I'm aiming for, there to be a MenuRegion (which I've already got working).
And, when the user clicks on some buttons, I need the MainRegion to refresh its view - depending on the selection of course.

---

In Addition, I'm also looking up on information on how to keep track of the changes made when trying to switch the view. Any suggestions?

---

I really hope you can help me out on this one!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know your situation very well. I have the same language history and started programming WPF some months ago. The **bad Google support for VB.NET** in general and especially for WPF related themes was the final cause for me to switch to C#. The language looks different, but it isn’t. Mixing both languages with (old) business logic projects in VB.NET and (new) WPF projects in C# is no problem.

So here is my advice: Take the next step and switch to C#, starting with the UI parts of your project.

Comment: Thank you Dirk. I did already considered switching. I can read and understand C# sourcecode, but i'm not able to write it at the speed i'm writing my VB.NET code. You should know i started way back in the days with Qbasic :) Can you provide me some usefull links that helped you out switching? Thanks!

Comment: Fortunately this is a question I asked one year ago :-) Here is the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4009691/searching-systematic-comprehensive-and-complete-comparison-between-the-syntax-o